# Русскоязычная документация по curl (libcurl)

Tags: c, документация, curl, c++

Здравствуйте!

Моего английского не хватает, многое путаю. Вопрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста, русскоязычную документацию (или книжку) по библиотетке Curl (libcurl) для C или C++.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Libcurl - вики](http://ru.libcurl.wikia.com/wiki/Libcurlru_вики).